# "Suggested edit approval overridden" reversion and -2 for old post that still shows as edited by me

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, reputation, deleted-users

A couple years ago, I suggested an edit to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28379345/compute-stats-issue-on-impala-1-2-4). I was checking my rep history today to see how much I'd lost to answer downvotes that hadn't been deleted, and discovered that there was a pair of unexpected -2 entries with the same time on the same day. One was the usual "user removed", but one was "reverted", with the tooltip "suggested edit approval overridden". However, it's quite clear that the post still shows as being edited by me, the [revision list](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28379345/revisions) and [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28379345/timeline) still show approval, and the [suggestion itself](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6975214) is clearly still in favor. Nor are either of the listed approving users, or the post-owning user, deleted. But the last reviewer listed is Community ♦, presumably because the third reviewer required at the time has since been deleted. (Normally, Community ♦'s Approves come only after a corresponding Edit entry by someone who chose Improve Edit.)

What on earth is going on that causes this weird bug? Did I get a doubled-up penalty for having had a suggested edit approved, in part, by a now-deleted user? Because that's wrong in at least two ways: SO should *not* be reverting rep or edits if a reviewer who acted in good faith has since deleted their account, and (obviously) SO should *not* double up rep penalties.

Comment: The user was deleted, so [the vote that grants you the +2 for the edit was also deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279415). There's just a bug that causes [both entries to appear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297888/when-a-user-who-approved-an-edit-is-removed-an-incorrect-2-reverted-event-ap) in your history even though you only lost the reputation once.

Comment: @animuson: Not so, but far otherwise, since obviously Community ♦ *had* the approving vote transferred to it! And the one-rep owning user is still there, so clearly a high-rep user was deleted, exactly the case where the suggested edit *shouldn't* be reverted in any way.

Comment: No, technically speaking, *all* votes end up attached to the Community user at deletion. They just don't get deleted too if they're transferred to Community before the user deletion occurs. Note that a vote in review is also independent of the vote that gives the reputation.

Comment: @animuson: Well, that's not needlessly opaque at all….